# Determining if there is a password for the private part of the certificate

Tags: windows, certificate

Is it possible to somehow unambiguously determine that the private key container has a password? I just need to know if there is a password or not.

Comment: It would be pretty weird if the certificate didn't have a password or passphrase. And "private part" is not a known term.

Answer (score 1):

The header information in the key file will let you know if the key requires a passphrase to use. Open the file with text editor and look at the headers. Below are some examples:

```
Openvpn encrypted keyfile
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

OpenSSH encypted key file
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: .....

OepnSSH not encrypted
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBA..............
```

The key in the end is just a semi-random number. There is now inherit property to tell if a key is encrypted or not. So header information is required.